# Traversing DOM for string returns correctly, sometimes

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am testing chrome extension development with a simple content script which traverses the DOM and returns true if a given string is found.

On simple webpages the script returns correctly 100% but on more complex pages e.g. google search results, it may return true every 1 in 10 times on a page which has the given string.

I am using Crockfords DOM traversal algorithm and have even tried a different algorithm but it gives the same results. I am new to extensions and Javascript and unsure if this is some kind of asynchronous problem?

```
var exists = false;

function walkTheDOM(node) {
    // String search function 
    if (node.nodeType === 3)
        if (node.nodeValue.indexOf("today") > -1) 
            exists = true;

    // Continue recursive DOM traversal
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return exists;
}

if (walkTheDOM(document.body))
    alert("String exists in page.");
```

Comment: Why not just use *document.body.textContent*? Also, this will "walk the DOM" to the end, even if the text is found at the start.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that and `document.body.textContent.indexOf("string")` works great. It would still be interesting for me to find out why the DOM traversal technique i used returned so unreliably.

Comment: When are you running this check? It is possible the page is inserting dynamic content and you're checking too soon?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli—also, some content might be delivered in iframes so inaccessible by the OP's method.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli As I understand content scripts for chrome extensions are run after the DOM is loaded [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at)

Comment: @RobG I believe you are correct about the original method not picking up content in iframes, however it is the inconsistency of the return values which bothers me.

Comment: @CBerry They are run after the _initial_ content is loaded. The page can then, at some unspecified time, load more content via scripts. Google Search certainly does that. It fits what you describe.

Comment: @Xan Aha... that could explain it. What would be the best way to wait for even these scripts to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since pages' content may be dynamic (new content loaded after your code executes), you have 2 possibilities:

1. If you need to have a decision in deterministic time, just wait a bit. Set a timeout from when your script starts executing and check then.
2. If you are okay with changing the decision if a word appears later, your best bet is to run what you're already running, plus [set up a listener for DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener) and analyze the new/modified nodes.

You can combine both methods if your strategy is "detect ASAP, give up in deterministic time".